# Feeds tamper fetch data from external API

Tags: 7, feeds

I am using drupal_http_request and drupal_json_decode to retrive and parse json from an external API in the feeds tamper by using the execute php code plugin. My code is as follows:

```
$json = "https://api.coursera.org/api/onDemandSpecializations.v1?ids=".$field;
$response = drupal_http_request($json);
$data = drupal_json_decode($response->data);
return ($data['elements'][0]['name']);
```

**This returns a null value.**

The json is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken `{}` indicates that it is an object and `[]` means that the variable is an array, therefor, I would expect `$data->elements[0]->name` would be the way to get the value in your return statement.

To improve your code, I would advise to use the [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) (or [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)) functions to check whether the elements in $data exists

Comment: Thanks.Doesn't drupal_json_decode convert the json object into a PHP array ?

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Could you print out what is stored in $data (using [dpm()](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7.x-1.x))?

Comment: dpm($data) returns nothing, but $dpm($response) shows the corresponding json object. There must be some problem with the drupal_json_decode statement.

Comment: I changed the code to json_decode, and it works now. Thanks for the help @Watergate.